# Rails multiple SQL queries in one statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

In Rails, is there a way to run multiple SQL queries in one statement, say something like:

```
UPDATE `dvd_actor` SET actor = replace(actor, '&Oacute;', 'Ó');
UPDATE `dvd_actor` SET actor = replace(actor, '&Aacute;', CHAR(193));
UPDATE `dvd_actor` SET actor = replace(actor, '&Eacute;', CHAR(201));
UPDATE `dvd_actor` SET actor = replace(actor, '&Iacute;', CHAR(205));
```

All in a single query.

This is something I do in PHP to cleanup the database but Rails gives me an error after the first one. I'm guessing it's not the Rails way, just curious what the best way to do this in Rails would be.

Currently I have:

```
self.connection.execute("UPDATE `dvd_actor` SET actor = replace(actor, '&Oacute;', 'Ó');
UPDATE `dvd_actor` SET actor = replace(actor, '&Aacute;', CHAR(193));
..."
```

**Edit:**
I should explain that I think running them with gsub is a waste of resources, when it's a lot faster and efficient to handle it in SQL. I mean, why translate them to a loop in the API when SQL can handle it a lot better?

Answer (score 0):

I would translate all the replaces to Ruby code and then use [runner](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) to run it. Something like:

```
Dvd.all.each do |dvd|
  # your substitutions here
  dvd.actor= dvd.actor.gsub(/foo/,'bar')
  dvd.save
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I should have explained that I think running them with gsub is a waste of resources, when it's a lot faster and efficient to handle it in SQL. I mean, why translate them to a loop in the API when SQL can handle it a lot better?

Comment: Then you should not use Rails at all. Write a mysql script ;)

Comment: I've got a Rails API that I'm trying to migrate all my PHP API to it.